Getting distinct field values with utilizing index in DocumentDB
I have a DocumentDB database (engine 5.0.0) with a collection my_collection with just two fields

_id (UUID)
user (string)

(The real collection has of course more, but I created test collection with exactly just these two fields for the purpose of validating if what I observe is independent of my particular real case.)
Now I want to query for distinct values of user.
I fail to formulate this (in my opinion quite simple) query in a way to make use of an index (assume there are too many documents in total which we definitely don't want to need to scan, but there are not so many distinct users).
Therefore I created a (non-unique) index
{ "user": 1 }

Then, the query could be expressed as (in mongosh syntax)
db.my_collection.distinct("user")

or alternatively I could use an aggregation pipeline like
db.my_collection.aggregate(
    [
        "$group": { "_id": "$user" }
    ]
)

Note that I also tried with an additional "$sort": { "_id": 1 } after the group, but let me furthermore note that I don't necessarily need an ordered result but something in the docs indicated that to be able to use the index it is required to also sort the result, so I tried this out...
Due to the index I thought it could perform the query (all alternatives above to be honest) by even only looking at the index. Unfortunately, the query is always performed with a scan of the documents (or the index?). (This is an assumption since the response time "feels" proportional to the number of documents in the collection which I increased when performing isolated tests. I don't fully understand the explain response to be honest but it shows stage: 'AGGREGATE' for the distinct, and stage: 'HASH_AGGREGATE' for the aggregate query.)
I was then trying to force DocumentDB to use the index by adding hint: { "user": 1 } to the query, however, that is only supported by aggregate and not by distinct. When using with aggregate, I get the error message:
MongoServerError: Cannot use Hint for this Query. Index is multi key index , partial index or sparse index and query is not optimized to use this index.

But that does not make sense for me, because the index I use is neither multi key, partial nor sparse, at least I didn't specify any of these when creating it (but again, I don't fully understand it although I tried to read the documentation...)
So now I wonder

Why is the index not utilized for "immediately" finding the user values? (Due to the error message when specifying it in hint, I assume it just can't be used, leading to the next question...)
Why can't I use the index? (Maybe DocumentDB does not support it here? But the documentation does not indicate anything like that.)
Is there an alternative approach I should try?


EDIT
Additional information requested in the comments:
db.my_collection.explain("executionStats").distinct("user"):
{
  queryPlanner: {
    plannerVersion: 1,
    namespace: 'testdb.my_collection',
    winningPlan: {
      stage: 'AGGREGATE',
      inputStage: {
        stage: 'HASH_AGGREGATE',
        inputStage: {
          stage: 'PROJECTION',
          inputStage: {
            stage: 'IXONLYSCAN',
            indexName: 'user_1',
            direction: 'forward'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  executionStats: {
    executionSuccess: true,
    executionTimeMillis: '219.245',
    planningTimeMillis: '0.274',
    executionStages: {
      stage: 'AGGREGATE',
      nReturned: '1',
      executionTimeMillisEstimate: '217.264',
      inputStage: {
        stage: 'HASH_AGGREGATE',
        nReturned: '4',
        executionTimeMillisEstimate: '217.248',
        inputStage: {
          stage: 'PROJECTION',
          nReturned: '50000',
          executionTimeMillisEstimate: '155.232',
          inputStage: {
            stage: 'IXONLYSCAN',
            nReturned: '50000',
            executionTimeMillisEstimate: '56.970',
            indexName: 'user_1',
            direction: 'forward'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  serverInfo: {
    host: '...-cluster-instance-1',
    port: 27017,
    version: '5.0.0'
  },
  ok: 1,
  operationTime: Timestamp({ t: 1722928392, i: 1 })
}

(Note: the collection has 50k documents and 4 distinct values in user.)
And while we're at it, here is
db.my_collection.explain("executionStats").aggregate([{"$group":{"_id":"$user"}}]):
{
  queryPlanner: {
    plannerVersion: 1,
    namespace: 'testdb.test_distinct',
    winningPlan: {
      stage: 'HASH_AGGREGATE',
      inputStage: {
        stage: 'COLLSCAN'
      }
    }
  },
  executionStats: {
    executionSuccess: true,
    executionTimeMillis: '112.782',
    planningTimeMillis: '0.087',
    executionStages: {
      stage: 'HASH_AGGREGATE',
      nReturned: '4',
      executionTimeMillisEstimate: '112.654',
      inputStage: {
        stage: 'COLLSCAN',
        nReturned: '50000',
        executionTimeMillisEstimate: '67.115'
      }
    }
  },
  serverInfo: {
    host: '...-cluster-instance-1',
    port: 27017,
    version: '5.0.0'
  },
  ok: 1,
  operationTime: Timestamp({ t: 1722928895, i: 1 })
}


What does db.my_collection.explain("executionStats").distinct("user") tells you? It's better to rely on facts rather than assumptions.

Would you please attach the output of the explain plan? I understand that you are using DocumentDB, which may behave differently from native MongoDB. But currently it is not reproducible in mongo playground, as it is using DISTINCT_SCAN

Thanks for telling me how to produce a more verbose explain output (in the sense of "all stages"). I attached it. There we can see that it uses an IXONLYSCAN which, at least that's how I interpret it, tells us that (a) it is indeed using the index but (b) it can't make use of the fact that the index has only a small number of distinct values. Maybe I need to create a different type of index? But I didn't find something in the DocumentDB documentation pointing me to an implementation difference compared to MongoDB... (but maybe I missed something)

Note regarding the explain with "all stages": What I tried before was runCommand with explain as the command (.runCommand({ explain:{  aggregate: ... } })) and that shows only the last stage and the inputStage is rendered as [Object] in mongosh). Interesting that the explain(...)... will render the input stages as JSON ;)

(a) - yes, agree. (b) - why? There are not much of implementational details of Document DB. It's a proprietary DaaS, so implementation is down to the vendor. On the bright side of DaaS you can open a support ticket and get authoritative answer from the vendor.

as per Query db.my_collection.explain("executionStats").aggregate([{"$group":{"_id":"$user"}}]): your explain output should match collection name my_collection but explain plan Shows namespace: 'testdb.test_distinct', which means you have used collection test_distinct, Could you pls check index on that collection it must be missing index on user there...

@ProgrammerAnalyst Good catch - but that's a leftover of me trying to abstract away the "actual name" of the collection (my actual collection is called test_distinct in testdb, but in this post i claimed it's called my_collection for reasons of "abstraction")

@AlexBlex I just assumed that an index always stores each value only once (pointing to a "list" of documents), but that just might be a wrong assumption on which I built my whole expectation. Asking AWS support would be my next step - I just could not imagine that DocumentDB is so "dumb" to be honest. For me this is a very common use case of an index, definitely nothing complicated.

Fair assumption. I wouldn't speculate on the internals of DocumentDB, but if you bring replication for redundancy and sharding for horizontal scalability, the classical B+tree may just not fit into RAM of a single machine. e.g. Mongo does not guarantee uniqueness of a key if it is not part of the shard key, right? AWS is likely uses their own architecture how to implement indexes. DocumentDB is compatible with Mongo only on protocol level and only to certain degree. Implementation differs, and they may have other priorities than optimisation for covered queries.

It's an interesting question tho. If you can share the response from AWS support I am sure many will appreciate. I am happy to chip in and run the test on Atlas. Would be an interesting comparison - stages, timings etc
